# Matrix-Tree Theorem for rooted directed graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am working my way through the proof of the theorem on the pages: 3,4,5 in the script [here](http://math.mit.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-19.pdf). I understand almost everything but the most essential idea: how to connect `det(L_r)` with the summation over subgraphs: `H`. Just before the line: "We wish to write..." I undestand that we have obtained an explicit formula for the determinant. Later we construct the summation over subgraphs that (as it turns out later) counts all the rooted spanning trees. The problem is that I have no idea why there is equality of the later summation to the determinant. The formulas are similar but the ranges of summation is unclear to me and I am missing `d_i`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that he never actually says what it means for a subgraph $H$ of $\Gamma$ to arise from a $\sigma\in S_{n-1}$. (There’s also at least one typo on page $4$: ‘all vertices fixed by $H$’ in the paragraph that starts ‘We wish to write’ should be ‘all vertices fixed by $\sigma$’.) I ended up organizing the calculation a bit differently, though I used essentially the same ideas.

For $\sigma\in S_{n-1}$ let

$$p(\sigma)=\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i\in\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)}d_i\prod_{i\notin\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)}L_{i,\sigma(i)}\;,$$

and let

$$\Sigma=\left\{\sigma\in S_{n-1}:\forall i\notin\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)\,\big(\langle i,\sigma(i)\rangle\in E\big)\right\}\;.$$

As the author points out,

$$\prod_{i\notin\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)}L_{i,\sigma(i)}\ne 0$$

only for $\sigma\in\Sigma$, in which case

$$p(\sigma)=\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)(-1)^{n-1-|\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)|}\prod_{i\in\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)}d_i\;,$$

and

$$\det L_r=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n-1}}p(\sigma)=\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}p(\sigma)=\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)(-1)^{n-1-|\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)|}\prod_{i\in\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)}d_i\;.$$

Now fix $\sigma\in\Sigma$. Let $E_\sigma=\{\langle i,\sigma(i)\rangle:i\notin\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)\}$. Say that a subgraph $H$ of $\Gamma$ is *compatible* with $\sigma$ if each vertex $i\ne n$ of $H$ has out-degree $1$, and $E_\sigma$ is a subset of the edges of $H$. Suppose that $H$ is compatible with $\sigma$, and $i\in\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)$; then either vertex $i$ is in the tree part of $H$, or $i$ is in a cycle of $H$ wholly contained in $\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)$.

For each vertex $i\in\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)$ there are $d_i$ choices for the edge of $H$ leaving $i$, and the remaining edges of $H$ are precisely those in $E_\sigma$, so there are $\prod_{i\in\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)}d_i$ subgraphs $H$ of $\Gamma$ that are compatible with $\sigma$. Let $\mathscr{H}_\sigma$ be the set of such subgraphs. If the non-trivial cycles of $\sigma$ are $C_1^{(\sigma)},\ldots,C_{k(\sigma)}^{(\sigma)}$, then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k(\sigma)}\left|C_i^{(\sigma)}\right|=n-1-|\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)|\;,$$

so

$$\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)=(-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^{k(\sigma)}\big(|C_i^{(\sigma)}|-1\big)}=(-1)^{n-1-|\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)|-k(\sigma)}\;,$$

and

$$p(\sigma)=\sum_{H\in\mathscr{H}_\sigma}(-1)^{n-1-|\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)|-k(\sigma)}(-1)^{n-1-|\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)|}=\sum_{H\in\mathscr{H}_\sigma}(-1)^{k(\sigma)}\;.$$

Let $\mathscr{H}=\bigcup_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\mathscr{H}_\sigma$, and for each $H\in\mathscr{H}$ let $\Sigma_H=\{\sigma\in\Sigma:H\in\mathscr{H}_\sigma\}$. Note that $\sigma\in\Sigma_H$ if and only if $E_\sigma$ is a subset of the edges of $H$, which in turn is the case if and only $C_i^{(\sigma)}$ is a cycle of $H$ for $i-1,\ldots,k(\sigma)$. If the cycles of $H$ are $C_1^{(H)},\ldots,C_{\ell(H)}^{(H)}$, we can pick any subset of these to be the non-trivial cycles of $\sigma$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma_H}(-1)^{k(\sigma)}&=\sum_{I\subseteq[\ell(H)]}(-1)^{|I|}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\ell(H)}\binom{\ell(H)}i(-1)^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\ell(H)}\binom{\ell(H)}i(-1)^i\\
&=(1-1)^{\ell(H)}\\
&=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }\ell(H)=0\\
0,&\text{if }\ell(H)\ge 1\;.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Clearly $\ell(H)=0$ if and only if $H$ is an oriented spanning tree for $\Gamma$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\deg L_r&=\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}p(\sigma)\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\sum_{H\in\mathscr{H}_\sigma}(-1)^{k(\sigma)}\\
&=\sum_{H\in\mathscr{H}}\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma_H}(-1)^{k(\sigma)}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{H\in\mathscr{H}\\\ell(H)=0}}1\\
&=|\{H\in\mathscr{H}:H\text{ is an oriented spanning tree for }\Gamma\}|\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

Comment: @maciek: You’re welcome!

Comment: Could you help me little more along the way? In the section 1.3 of this script I am trying to generalize the formula into the Matrix-Tree Theorem for undirected graphs but I do not understand what is written after "It is true that"... Why is this true? There must be something about the characteristic polynomial that I am missing. Also later, in the last part of the proof: What happens to all the "t" and why do we get additional (-1)^n-1?