# Matrix-Tree Theorem: proof with graph characteristic polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

This is a follow-up question regarding my [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860300/matrix-tree-theorem-for-rooted-directed-graphs#_=_).
I went through the sections: 1.1 and 1.2 of the [following script](http://math.mit.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-19.pdf).
I am in the middle of the section 1.3 but I do not understand what is happening after the line:

> "It is true that"

Why is that equality true? What is represented by the coefficient of `t` in the characteristic polynomial?
ALso, later in the equations: what happens to that coefficient and where does the additional `(-1)^n-1` come from?

Comment: You beat me to it: I was just about to suggest that you make this a separate question, because the answer was getting rather long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that

$$\chi(t)=\det(tI-L)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n\left(t[k=\sigma(k)]-L_{k,\sigma(k)}\right)\;,\tag{1}$$

where $[k=\sigma(k)]$ is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), equal to $1$ if $k=\sigma(k)$ and to $0$ otherwise. The terms in the summation on the righthand side of $(1)$ that contribute to the $t$ term in the polynomial $\chi(t)$ are those for which $\sigma$ has exactly one fixed point. Suppose that $r\in[n]$ is a fixed point of $\sigma$; then

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n\left(t[k=\sigma(k)]-L_{k,\sigma(k)}\right)&=\left(\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{\substack{k\in[n]\\k\ne r}}(-L_{k,\sigma(k)})\right)(t-d_r)\\
&=\left((-1)^{n-1}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{\substack{k\in[n]\\k\ne r}}L_{k,\sigma(k)}\right)(t-d_r)\;,
\end{align*}$$

which contributes

$$(-1)^{n-1}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{\substack{k\in[n]\\k\ne r}}L_{k,\sigma(k)}$$

to the coefficient of $t$ in $\chi(t)$.

Now let $\hat\sigma\in S_{n-1}$ be defined from $\sigma$ as follows:

$$\hat\sigma(k)=\begin{cases}
\sigma(k),&\text{if }k,\sigma(k)<r\\
\sigma(k)-1,&\text{if }k<r\text{ and }\sigma(k)>r\\
\sigma(k-1),&\text{if }k>r\text{ and }\sigma(k)<r\\
\sigma(k-1)-1,&\text{if }k,\sigma(k)>r
\end{cases}$$

Since $\sigma(r)=r$, $\sigma$ induces a permutation of $[n]\setminus\{r\}$; $\hat\sigma$ is the ‘same’ permutation of $[n-1]$ after each member of $[n]$ greater than $r$ has been reduced by $1$. Thus, $\operatorname{sgn}(\hat\sigma)=\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$, and in fact

$$(-1)^{n-1}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{\substack{k\in[n]\\k\ne r}}L_{k,\sigma(k)}=(-1)^{n-1}\operatorname{sgn}(\hat\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}L_{k,\hat\sigma(k)}^{(r)}\;,$$

where $L_{i,j}^{(r)}$ is the $\langle i,j\rangle$ entry in the Laplacian matrix $L_r$.

It follows that the permutations in $S_n$ that fix $r$ contribute a total of

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{\sigma\in S_n\\\sigma(r)=r}}(-1)^{n-1}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{\substack{k\in[n]\\k\ne r}}L_{k,\sigma(k)}&=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n-1}}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}L_{k,\sigma(k)}^{(r)}\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\det L_r\;.
\end{align*}$$

to the coefficient of $t$ in $\chi(t)$. The entire coefficient of $t$ is then obtained by summing over $r$: it’s

$$[t]\chi(t)=\sum_{r=1}^n(-1)^{n-1}L_r=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{r=1}^n\det L_r\;,$$

and on multiplying by $(-1)^{n-1}$ we have

$$(-1)^{n-1}[t]\chi(t)=\sum_{r=1}^n\det L_r\;.$$

---

In the final calculation the expression

$$[t]\prod_{i=1}^n(t-\lambda_i)$$

is the coefficient of $t$ in the polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^n(t-\lambda_i)$. Before like terms in the product are collected, there are $n$ first degree terms: for each $r\in[n]$ we have the term

$$t\prod_{\substack{k\in[n]\\k\ne r}}(-\lambda_k)\;.$$

However, $\lambda_n=0$, so all of these are $0$ except the $r=n$ term,

$$t\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(-\lambda_k)=\left((-1)^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\lambda_k\right)t\;,$$

so the coefficient of $t$ in $\prod_{k=1}^n\lambda_k$ is

$$(-1)^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\lambda_k\;;$$

that’s where the second $(-1)^{n-1}$ comes from.

Comment: I do not understand one small detail:  
In the beginning: suppose that `r` is a fixed point of a given permutation. It seems to me that in the product of all brackets you are missing the one corresponding to `r`. The Iverson bracket is then "1" and we got `(t-L_r,r)`. There is no trace of that on the righthand side of the second equation. Instead - you just omit that part and change the range of the product to: `k != r`. Why is that equality true?

Comment: @maciek: $L_{r,r}=0$, so the $k=r$ factor is $t$; that's the $t$ at the end of the expression, outside the large parentheses.

Comment: Allright, I understand now that `L` is the Laplacian Matrix of the graph directed to `r`. Then, actually, you are right: `deg(r)=0`. But then - does the root of the trees always has to be the fixed point of the permutations that give coefficients to `t`? Why?

Comment: @maciek: The tree doesn't even have to be rooted; I used $r$ because the paper does, but I could just as well have used $s$, say, for the vertex that is fixed by $\sigma$.

Comment: I am sorry, I got a little confused.  
Why is, then, `L_r,r = 0` ?  
Also, I see now that the final product is of the eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix of the graph directed towards `r=n`. but in the matrix-tree theorem we utilize the matrix of the undirected graph.

Comment: @maciek: Sorry: what I wrote in the answer wasn’t quite right — I got a little bit ahead myself — and my comment about $L_{r,r}$ being $0$ is flat wrong. (I was working from memory at the time, without the original notes in front of me.) I’ve fixed it now. $L_{r,r}$ is actually $d_r$, but it doesn’t matter, because that part of the $\langle r,r\rangle$ entry in $tI-L$ doesn’t contribute to the $t$ term in $\chi(t)$; it’s only the $t$ part of $t-d_r$ that does.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I went through the script once again with your notes and it is all clear and obvious now. You are indeed a great mathematician!

Comment: @maciek: You're welcome, and thank *you*.